# Want facebook id for locations

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I am using graph API to post on Facebook. I want Geo targeting to post. So fetch Facebook id for Bangalore which is 1017930. but when i am using this id targeting is not happening, whereas i got this id for same place on net 106377336067638 when this is used targeting happening successfully.
To fetch id I had used this query - https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=in&type=adregion
SO my question is from where i will get list of ids for locations?

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Bangalore&type=adcity

In the JSON response you can find the key (ID) of the selected city. To fetch all you will need to use the paging feature and iterate through a list with the cities you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks. But if read question again you will see what exactly I am facing. This URL is returning the id but that id is not valid when I am using it for post method.
Please check this URL - https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed?message=Hey&place=1017930

Comment: @user3933077 I got you now. So actually the place is a page ID of the place you want to post to. So for example - for bangalore the page is https://www.facebook.com/pages/Bangalore-India/106377336067638. And the ID comes from here. Also there is a different bangalore with id 342956752438463 which redirects to the same page. I guess your best bet is to execute something like- search?q=Bangalore-India&type=place and take the first result (i tested it for a couple of different cities) and it works as expected.